# Tracking a moving device using BTLE

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking for a way to be able to track another BTLE-enabled iOS device using mine, while within range. Basically, one device would have to log it's geolocation info, and then send it periodically to the other device, using BTLE.

How would I be able to do this? In general, I haven't been able to find much info on how to send and receive messages via BTLE, so any help in that category would be great. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323680/transmitting-data-with-corebluetooth) answer already, but it didn't help me much, and I'm wondering if anything has changed since then.

If not possible through Apple's built-in framework, do you know of any external ones that would allow for this?

Comment: Look at Apple's [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927) example, which shows how to transmit data over LE between two iOS devices (requires iOS 6.0, though). All you'd need is to craft a custom profile to transmit your location coordinates as attributes.

Comment: Do you know how BLE works ? If not, I'd say this: Play with two iDevice with the app LightBlue (app on the AppStore wich could "replace" the thermometer). Then use Temperature Sensor (sample from Apple) combined with LightBlue. Once you get to understand how BLE works, you could learn about the previous sample given by Brad. When I say play, it doesn't mean that you won't need to go through the BLE documentation and the Apple doc of CoreBluetooth.framework, but that you can test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long, long, long, longgg story short, but here ya go:

On one iOS device, adopt both the CBCentralManager and CBPeripheralManager. The CBCentralManager is responsible for connecting to external peripherals and maintaining that connection. The CBPeripheralManager will be what you'll use to read/write from the iOS device that your using a peripheral.

On the other iOS device, adopt just the CBPeripheralManager. You'll need add all the services and characteristics into the CBPeripheralManager that are stated in the GATT profile. Check out developer.bluetooth.org. These services and characteristics are necessary in order to connect from one device to the other.

In addition to just the gatt characteristics and services, you'll need to add in a custom service with a characteristic that you store your location data.

Check out the docs but for CBPeripheralManager in particularly you'll need to utilize

```
-(void) peripheralManager:(BLEPeripheralManager*)mgr requiresResponseToWriteRequests:(NSArray*)requests;
```

and

```
-(void) peripheralManager:(BLEPeripheralManager*)mgr requiresResponseToReadRequest:(CBATTRequest*)request;
```

in order to pass the location data between devices..Sorry for the brief overview, but there's just way too much to write up quickly.

Comment: Short, but quite useful. I won't know if it works exactly like I want till we're done, but an outline like this is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I'm working on it now but there seems to be an issue. Is it possible for both of the devices to be able to send and receive data to each other in the same connection? Right now it seems like only one has to broadcast while the other subscribes to get the data. What I'm looking to do is have them both be able to track each other simultaneously. Or do I have to do this by rapidly renewing the connection and changing the central/peripheral status of the devices?

Comment: Oh wait i forgot your question..So you want both to be able to write location coordinates to each other?

Comment: Yes! Do you think that's doable?

Comment: I will gladly give you reputation points/bounty btw, if you care about that.

Comment: haha yes, its 100% doable. I'm busy right now, but I'll comment later to give you pointers